# Obtaining the Psi Weights of a seasonal ARIMA in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima

I am trying to quantify the effect of a future random shocks on my seasonal ARIMA model. If I have understood the theory correctly, the easiest way is to express my seasonal ARIMA model in its "random shock" form, and calculate the corresponding psi weights.

Is there a way to do this in R? There is ARMAtoMA, but I think this only works for ARMA models, and not seasonal ARIMA models.

Thank you for your help.

---

UPDATE: Apologies, I'll post the question about R onto stack overflow. It would be good to get confirmation that this is the correct method to quantify the effect of future random shocks to a seasonal ARIMA model.

Comment: If you are *only* asking how to do this in R, this question would be off-topic for CV (see our [help center](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)). It might do well on the r-help listserv, though. Please clarify your question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to use R.

Comment: You can define the input to `ARMAtoMA` by multiplying the non-seasonal and seasonal polynomials. If you post the link to your question at stack overflow I could give you more details.